# How to use "gesture" in UWP inkcanvas

Tags: uwp, gesture, inkcanvas

Hello I want to add some customized gesture (i made) functions on inkcanvas

But I don't know how to do that when the inputdevicetype is touch like this

```
inkcanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
```

when the input device type is touch, then i can't use any gestures

Because the all inputs are recognized the drawn

when using inkcanvas with touch input, can't i use gesture functions?

```
private void ink1_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
            PointerDeviceType pointerDevType = e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType;

            pointers = new Dictionary<uint, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer>();

            e.Handled = true;

            PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(ink1);
            m_pt.Add(ptrPt);

            if (!pointers.ContainsKey(ptrPt.PointerId))
            {
                // Add contact to dictionary.
                pointers[ptrPt.PointerId] = e.Pointer;
            }               

            switch (ptrPt.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType)
            {
                case Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse:                       
                    ink1.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
                    ink1.RightTapped += ink1_RightTapped;

                    break;

                case PointerDeviceType.Touch:
                    if (m_pt.Count == 2)
                    {                            
                        ink1.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.None;
                        ink1.RightTapped += ink1_RightTapped;                          


                    }
                    else if (m_pt.Count == 1 || m_pt.Count > 2)
                    {
                        ink1.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
                        ink1.RightTapped += ink1_RightTapped;

                    }

                break;

            }         


    }
```

When i press my ink1(inkcanvas) with 2 fingers, then i want to use my gesture functions (draw letter L or tap the inkcanvas 3 times) what i made

such as uwp's doubletapped, righttapped etc.

Comment: " i can't use any gestures", could you please for example?

Comment: Well For example, I can open an image file by drawing an alphabet "L" 
or when I double tap with two fingers ,then i can open a video file on the inkcanvas.

Comment: I'm still  confused about your issue.You could upload some code snippet that can work well when the `inputdevicetype` is not touch.  Why you open a video file with InkCanvas?

Answer (score 1):

I saw you use the `PointerPress` event handle for `InkCanvas`.
The configuration of the `InkPresenter` determines the pointer event handling behavior of the `InkCanvas`. You must set `InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes` to `CoreInputDeviceTypes.None` for the `InkCanvas` to process pointer events, otherwise they are passed to the `InkPresenter` object.

To handle pointer events with the `InkPresenter` object, you must set `RightDragAction` to `LeaveUnprocessed` to pass the input through as `UnprocessedInput` for custom processing by your app.

```
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.RightDragAction =  InkInputRightDragAction.LeaveUnprocessed;
```

Details please reference the remark section of [`InkCanvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas).

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to know about the pointer event. And it only for pen, mouse input right? not touch input

Comment: @Kay, this answer means  if your input type is pen or touch , you should set as above mentioned. Which contains touch input.